# Conditional processing on last item in a range

Tags: python, range

I am trying to do conditional processing according to when we are at the last item in a range, for example:

```
for i in range(intNumberOfPlayers):            
        #If we are on the last item in the range, do this...
```

Comment: What problem are you experiencing, specifically?

Comment: I had a iterator variable keeping track of i, and if i == intIterator i would do further processing or else if it didn't. intIterator works if intNumberOfPlayer == 2 given that intIterator (i+1) because it would match i second iteration, but this would not work 3 or more times and that was the problem, but the solution below fixes it.

Comment: It would be worth adding more detail to the question so that it is more useful to others in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in range(intNumberOfPlayers):
    if i == intNumberOfPlayers - 1:
        print(i) #print last item
```

Ranges are not inclusive, so the last item is `intNumberOfPlayers - 1`